# Php add new Json Object

Tags: php, json, object

I got an Json object

```
{"cms18.test.silverbee.nl":{"domain":"cms18","template":"default"},"dmmd.test.silverbee.nl":{"domain":"dmmd","template":"default"},"opmaat.test.silverbee.nl":{"domain":"opmaat","template":"opmaat"},"opmaatdebiteurenadvies.nl":{"domain":"opmaat","template":"opmaat"},"navbar.test.silverbee.nl":{"domain":"navbar","template":"default"},"test18.test.silverbee.nl":{"domain":"test18testsilverbeenl","template":"test"},"huisartsplus.test.silverbee.nl":{"domain":"huisartsplustestsilverbeenl","template":"huisartsplus"},"robertenrademaker.test.silverbee.nl":{"domain":"robertenrademakertestsilverbeenl","template":"robert-en-rademaker"},"tilburg.test.silverbee.nl":{"domain":"tilburgtestsilverbeenl","template":"default"},"cbk-groningen.test.silverbee.nl":{"domain":"cbk_groningentestsilverbeenl","template":"cbk-groningen"},"getbusyinc.test.silverbee.nl":{"domain":"getbusyinctestsilverbeenl","template":"getbusyinc"}}
```

And i want to add/push a new php string i made to it and i have it like this i am not sure if it is correct.

```
<?php
    $list= file_get_contents('list.json');
    $list = json_decode($list, true);

    include('veranderen.php');


    // Het toevoegen van een nieuwe URL
    $url = $_POST['new_url'];
    $t_d = $_POST['t_d']; 
    $t_t = $_POST['t_t'];
    $str[$url] = "{domain:".$t_d.","."template:".$t_t."},";

    include('delete.php');
    include('interface.php');
    include('lijst.php');
?>
```

Comment: if you are decoding an json_object than push each value in decoded array then encode it again and replace the file content.

Comment: Your variable is `$list`, but you are changing `$str`. Should be `$list[$url]`. And don't add new values as JSON string. Add it as array and then `json_encode` it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you decode a json string in PHP you get an associative array.

So you could just

```
$list[$url] = array("domain" => $t_d, "template" => $t_t);
```

and then encode it and rewrite your list.json.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try something like this

```
<?php
    $list= file_get_contents('list.json');
    $list = json_decode( $list, true );

   include('veranderen.php');


    $url = $_POST['new_url'];
    $t_d = $_POST['t_d']; 
    $t_t = $_POST['t_t'];

    $tmp=array();
    $tmp[ $url ] = array( 'domain'=>$t_d, 'template'=>$t_t );
    $list = json_encode( array_merge( $list, $tmp ), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT );
    $bytes=file_put_contents('list.json', $list, FILE_TEXT )

    include('delete.php');
    include('interface.php');
    include('lijst.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see in your sample code that you're building your JSON using string concatenation `$str[$url] = "{domain:".$t_d.","."template:".$t_t."},";`

I would recommend that you learn about PHP's built-in `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` functions -- these allow you to work with JSON without ever having to mess around with the actual string value.

Build the data structure you want to output as a normal PHP array or object structure, and then just pass it in to `json_encode()` to get the finished string.

You started the question with a pre-existing string. If you have built that already inside your PHP code, then I suggest recoding to build it as a PHP array, and only use `json_encode()` when you finally come to output it. This will allow you to add or change data in it anywhere in your program.

If you've recieved that JSON string from somewhere else (ie you get the string already in the JSON format), then use `json_decode()` to turn it into a PHP array/object structure first, work with it in that form within your PHP program, and then use `json_encode()` to turn it back into a JSON string again when you're ready to output it.